# Opening a screenshot image in another activity

Tags: android, image, android-intent, bitmap

I created an application to take a screen shot of the current screen and then open the image in a new activity. For some reason my application crashes when i want to open the new activity to view the picture. Here's my code:

```
public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
    View screenView = view.getRootView();
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

This is the onSave method that gets the image and is meant to set and display the image in another activity:

```
 public void onSave(View view){
   Bitmap bm = getScreenShot(view);

    ImageView view= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newView);
    view.setImageBitmap(bm);

   Intent saveIntent = new Intent(this, SavePicture.class);
   startActivity(saveIntent);

}
```

This is the saveIntent activity XML code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/saveView"
    android:contentDescription=""
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the MANIFEST

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.krypttech.gallery">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SavePicture">

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show the crash stacktrace?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/take-a-screenshot-programmatically-in-android/). Here you need to pass taken screenshot uri path to next activity using intent and read the uri in new activity using getIntent().

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.krypttech.gallery.MainActivity.onSave(MainActivity.java:207)

Comment: @W.Bright post your full stack trace log

Comment: `ImageView view` is already defined in the scope by `View view` (the argument of your function `onSave`). So try to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, this code crashes

```
  ImageView view= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newView);
    view.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

reason:
`view` is `null`.

*comment*

previously I said that the application may crash due to `bm` is `null`. But @greenapps in comments said that wrong. That's why I've changed my post and removed this 'possible' choice.

Comment: `bm is null.`. No. No problem. You can use `null` to 'clear' an ImageView.

Comment: And you were wrong editing your post. As now my comment is nonsense. There was not any reason to edit your post.

Comment: the code works fine if I open the Image in an ImageView of the main activity. Just don't know why it doesn't open in another activity

Comment: @greenapps , specially for you:)

Comment: My god ... you dont have to do a confession ... ;-).

Comment: @W.Bright , your comment does describe nothing. Post more code: xml, java, etc

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this by passing the Bitmap through the Intent. Had to compress the Bitmap to byte though.

```
public  void onSave(View view){
    Bitmap bm = getScreenShot(view);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    Intent previewIntent = new Intent(this, SavePicture.class);
    previewIntent.putExtra("Bitmap", byteArray);

    startActivity(previewIntent);
}
```

Then this is the receiving activity

```
public class SavePicture extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.save_activity);

    byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("Bitmap");
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    ImageView saveView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.saveView);
    saveView.setImageBitmap(bm);
}

}
```